# Does fl parameter makes search faster in solr?

Tags: solr

I am using solr for search and want to know if I should use **fl** means field parameter. By using it, will search be fater?

Answer (score 0):

Search itself won't be faster, but you could see gains for *very large* result sets. The data returned over the wire will be smaller and Solr / Lucene won't have to retrieve the content of the fields that aren't returned.

How much it'll actually change improve your application's performance in a measurable way depends on too many factors to give a definitive answer. It won't affect the response time negatively, but you'll have to spend more time maintaining which data to return from your queries for each type of query you're making.

Usually if you're not using the data (if none of your queries require the actual data) you can ask Solr to not store the actual data for the field instead.